# LinkedResource using Array

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have an array Attachmentlocation which contains all the .png files from my destination folder.
AttachmentLocation = Directory.GetFiles(destinationPath, "*.png");

the png files have name like
1CC
2CC
4CC
5CC
7CC

This is if I want to attach one file:

LinkedResource image = new LinkedResource(AttachmentLocation[0], "image/png");
image.ContentId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

How can we make it dynamic using an array of LinkedResource ? read all the files from the folder and like 3CC and 6CC are missing so use an alternate image path for missing ones. Can anyone help on this?

Comment: do you want to display all the pictures on a page? And how can there be missing files that you need to substitute the picture when you JUST pulled the list from a existing folder?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: im generating images with phantomjs. if there is no data for a specific highchart, the image doesnot generate. i need to generate 9 images but if 2 are missing i need to add the nodatafound image in the email for those divisions.